# How to use AutoValue with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, auto-value

I've got AutoValue (and the android-apt plugin) working in a project, and I'm aware of Ryan Harter's gson extension for AutoValue, but how do I hook Retrofit 2 up to use the extension and factory method on the abstract class?

```
String grantType = "password";
Call<SignIn> signInCall = retrofitApi.signIn(email, password, grantType);
signInCall.enqueue(callback);
```

eg here I would like to use AutoValue with the SignIn JSON model object to enforce immutability but how do I hook up Retrofit (or perhaps more specifically Gson) to the immutable, AutoValue model class?

Answer (score 26):

[update] The library have changed a bit, check more here: https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson

I was able to make it work like this. I hope it will help you.

- Import in your gradle app file

  `apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.3.1'`
- Create object with autovalue:

  ```
  @AutoValue public abstract class SignIn {    
      @SerializedName("signin_token") public abstract String signinToken();
      @SerializedName("user") public abstract Profile profile();

      public static TypeAdapter<SignIn> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
          return new AutoValue_SignIn.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
      }
  }
  ```
- Create your Type Adapter Factory  (Skip if using version > 0.3.0)

  ```
  public class AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

      public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
          Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();

          if (rawType.equals(SignIn.class)) {
              return (TypeAdapter<T>) SignIn.typeAdapter(gson);
          } 

          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- Create your Gson converter with your GsonBuilder

  ```
  GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(
          new GsonBuilder()
                  .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory())
                  .create());
  ```
- Add it to your retrofit builder

  ```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
          .Builder()
          .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
          .baseUrl("http://url.com/")
          .build()
  ```
- Do your request
- Enjoy

**Bonus live template:**
In your autovalue class, type avtypeadapter then autocomplete to generate the type adapter code.  To work you need to add this as a [live template in Android Studio](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html).

```
public static TypeAdapter<$class$> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
    return new AutoValue_$class$.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
}
```

[image: Live template configuration]

**How to create and use the live template.**

[image: Live template gif]

Comment: great explanation, appreciate it. I have most of the part working but I am not able to find AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory. Keep getting this error

"Error:(40, 57) error: cannot find symbol class AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory"

Comment: You have to use @GsonTypeAdapterFactory on an abstract class that implements TypeAdapterFactory. Check it there https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson#factory

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Gist by Jake Wharton for a Gson TypeAdapterFactory that just requires you add an annotation to all of your AutoValue classes that require working with Gson
https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/0d67d01badcee0ae7bc9

Works great for me.

Here's some proguard help too..

```
-keep class **.AutoValue_*
-keepnames @yourpackage.AutoGson class *
```