# Using Retrofit 2.0 with Autovalue

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, auto-value, gson

I am trying to use AutoValue library from [here](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel)

I have using Retrofit 2.0 for web service call, all web service request getting failed with HTTP Request error 400. By further investigation I got to know that I have to set the `TypeAdapterFactory` and pass it to Retrofit Builder like

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
    .Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
    .baseUrl("http://url.com/")
    .build()
```

This answer is available at [How to use AutoValue with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529238/how-to-use-autovalue-with-retrofit-2#)

But the `gsonConverterFactory` being used there is like

```
public class AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();

    if (rawType.equals(SignIn.class)) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) SignIn.typeAdapter(gson);
    } 

    return null;
}
```

}

where `rawType.equals(SignIn.class)` is being used, so my question is, is there any way to make generic version of `AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory` or I have to create separate `AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory` for each web service request with respective DTO??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> To generate a TypeAdapterFactory for all of your auto-value-gson
>   classes, simply create an abstract class that implements
>   TypeAdapterFactory and annotate it with @GsonTypeAdapterFactory, and
>   auto-value-gson will create an implementation for you. You simply need
>   to provide a static factory method, just like your AutoValue classes,
>   and you can use the generated TypeAdapterFactory to help Gson
>   de/serialize your types.

[from gson extension documentation](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson#factory)

Create the below factory method to handle

```
@GsonTypeAdapterFactory
public abstract class MyAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

  // Static factory method to access the package
  // private generated implementation
  public static TypeAdapterFactory create() {
    return new AutoValueGson_MyAdapterFactory();
  }

}
```

register an instance of the factory :

```
GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(
                new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(AutoValueGsonTypeAdapterFactory.create())
                        .create());
```

and then add it to retrofitclient as

```
Retrofit retrofitClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.END_POINT)
                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .build();
```